# Find an equation tangent to the graph of y=f(x) at the point where x=-3 if f(-3)=2 and f'(-3)=5 [stuck]

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

> Problem: Find an equation tangent to the graph of y=f(x) at the point
> where x=-3  if f(-3)=2 and f'(-3)=5

What I've tried:
I tried solving this the way "normal" tangent equations are found when the problem gives a point and an equation (y=Mx+b).[Using slope-intercept to then derivate]

I attempted finding Y1 and X1 (as one would do to solve for a point using Y-Y1=m(x-x1))

Where x1 =-3 [As given by the problem]
[The only equation given is] Y=f(x) [plugin-in "-3" results in] f(-3)) = Y

The problem establishes that f(-3)=2
Therefore, we have found y=2 & x1=-3

If I were to attempt to substitute this in order to "derivate" (as in a normal problem where  asked to find a tangent and a point is given and solved trough slope intercept, then trough derivation):

y=f(x)

y'=f'(x)
f'(-3) = 2 //How could I derivate this?, here is probably my mistake, though I do not know how to approach it in another way.

[Then the problems establishes *"and f'(-3)=5"* so according to the problem f'(-3)=5 NOT 2, therefore I did something wrong and clearly can not be solved this way]

I am completely stuck here really. How can I find the equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tangent has the slope $f'(-3)=5$ and passes through the point $(-3,f(-3))=(-3,2)$. Take $y=Mx+b$ and substitute $M=f'(-3)=5$ and the tangent becomes $y=5x+b$. Now, substituting $(-3,2)$ gives $b=2-5(-3)=17$. So, the tangent is $y=5x+17$.

The slope of this tangent would be $\frac{dy}{dx}=5$ which is the same as the slope of the curve $f(x)$ at the point $(-3,2)$.

Comment: Understood, thank you a lot for your help!. Have a great day.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it helped. And have a great day too!

Answer (score 2):

You are told the gradient and a point on the line. **This is not a calculus question** (except to the extent that you need to interpret the derivative as telling you the gradient at the point). It's just a "substitute and solve for $c$" question.

You already have the method required in your question: substitute $y_1=2$, $x_1=-3$, and $m=5$.

You definitely do not need to 'derivate' $y=f(x)$, even if you could. The way you have tried to do so is just wrongly copying the value from $f(x)$, which is almost certain to be wrong (it would be a total fluke if that happens to work for a given derivative).